# shiny substitute reactive value in a vector

Tags: r, shiny

I want to substitute some -Inf in a reactive numeric vector
in a Shiny script. The complete script is very large, so
just consider the following lines:

x  <- reactive( { log(seq(0,10,2),10) } )

the result is:

-Inf 0.3010300 0.6020600 0.7781513 0.9030900 1.0000000

In order to substitute -Inf by 0 I tried:

y <- reactive( { x()[x()==-Inf] <-  0 } )

but,

Warning: Error in <-: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

Do you know what is the correct way of doing that?

I know this is probably a basic question but I
couldn't find the answer in previous posts.

Thanks

Juan

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y <- reactive({
        y <- x()
        y[y == -Inf] <- 0
        return(y) })
```

I assign the x() to y first and then change the -Inf to 0 and return the new vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare against Inf  using the helper functions is.infinite() or is.finite()

```
y <- reactive({
   y <- x()
   y [is.infinite(x())] <- 0
   return(y) 
})
```